# Instead of trigger behavior with CDC Tables

Tags: sql-server

We're having an insted of trigger on view ( for DML operations ) .
we are trying to monitor the Activity on the view with CDC Tables and we've defined the base table (the one the view is based on ) as a CDC table .

When we run an update command on the view ( the instead of trigger is fired ) the output in the cdc tables is one row for delete and one row for update ( operation code 1 and then operation code 2 ) , we expected to find one row with the value bedore ( operation code 3 ) and one row with the value after ( operation code 4).

Do you know if this the normal behavior when update occures when instead of trigger is fired behind the scene (delete old record and insert new record ) ?

Thx for the help .

Answer (score 0):

Any update can be implemented as a split update (delete old value, insert new value). The Query Processor does so typically to guard for [Halloween Protection](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/craigfr/archive/2008/02/27/halloween-protection.aspx) (and you had to post your question today!). Your particular update had a wide plan (split update). You should always be prepared to handle this case, so it doesn't really matter *why* it happened. Whether having an instead-of-update trigger forces a wide plan or not is an orthogonal issue.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the quick responed. what if my instead of trigger is updating every time only one row (unique row ) but it updates 20 columns in that row , is it also can cause asplit update ?

Comment: Hi , I've altered the trigger to update only one column (insted of 20 ) and the CDC tables are now getting the before\after operations( code 3 and 4) it seems when there is awide range of columns , although we are updating one row , it uses delete insert . thx for your explaination , Happy Halloween :)